# Tab slide out using jQuery - need more than one

Tags: jquery

I'm using the Tab Slide Out Jquery plugin.
http://wpaoli.building58.com/2009/09/jquery-tab-slide-out-plugin/

I have one tab that appears on the left, but i wanted another independent tab on the right.
When i duplicate the blocks of css, js and the div, the tab on the right appears but i can only activate the one on the left if i activate the one on the right.

Also the contact image only appears on the right, so i can only activate the right tab.
How can i code this so that i can have more than one tab on one page and activate them independently?

```
 $(function(){
         $('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
             tabHandle: '.handle',                              //class of the element that will be your tab
             pathToTabImage: 'images/contact_tab.gif',          //path to the image for the tab (optionaly can be set using css)
             imageHeight: '122px',                               //height of tab image
             imageWidth: '40px',                               //width of tab image    
             tabLocation: 'left',                               //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
             speed: 300,                                        //speed of animation
             action: 'click',                                   //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
             topPos: '200px',                                   //position from the top
             fixedPosition: false                               //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
         });

         $('.slide-out-div-apps').tabSlideOut({
             tabHandle: '.handle',                              //class of the element that will be your tab
             pathToTabImage: 'images/contact_tab.gif',          //path to the image for the tab (optionaly can be set using css)
             imageHeight: '122px',                               //height of tab image
             imageWidth: '40px',                               //width of tab image    
             tabLocation: 'right',                               //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
             speed: 300,                                        //speed of animation
             action: 'click',                                   //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
             topPos: '200px',                                   //position from the top
             fixedPosition: false                               //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
         });


     });
```

Here's my css

```
.slide-out-div {
   padding: 20px;
    width: 250px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border: #29216d 2px solid;
}

.slide-out-div-apps {
   padding: 20px;
    width: 250px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border: #29216d 2px solid;
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you ever get this to work? I have the same problem. Please let me know how you solved it. Thanks

Comment: Hi - Yes, i got this to work. Do you want me to post the solution here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is tabHandle: '.handle

To solve this add another class to each .handle so for instance you could have .handle.first and .handle.second

This way each trigger is unique. Cheers

Comment: Oh ok. I see you solved it too. I also solved it in the same way. Well done. I marked your answer as accepted. ;-)

Comment: Hi Khuram, with your solution did it still work in IE7 & 8? Mine does not display at all in those browsers. Thanks

Comment: Hi - I'm afraid i am on IE9 (or 10 i think), but it seems to be working in IE. Here is my version, please feel free to copy the javascript

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3417415/tabSlideOut/tabSlideOut.html

Comment: Never mind, it worked the whole time, I just had a conflicting script or something on the page I was trying to implement it on. Cheers