# Need help customizing a Tab slide out plugin using jQuery and CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask or not but I found this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645702/tab-slide-out-using-jquery-need-more-than-one) related to a plugin I was playing around with and I wanted to see if anyone knows how to go about making this so you can add this plugin to a menu.

For example, I want to have four buttons on the menu that are next to each other across the top of the page. When you click the Search button or the Newsletter button it will slide down a form where you can enter your search term and click GO or enter your email address and click Subscribe. For the other two buttons I just want them to link to other web pages. I haven't used jQuery before but I am familiar with java, javascript, and HTML and CSS.

An example of what I'd like to do can be seen at http://visittheoregoncoast.com/ at the top right of the web page. When you click search or Email Newsletter the whole menu slides down and a small form is revealed.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved with both JQuery and mootools here are some links that might help you:

- [Sliding Login Panel with Mootools 1.2](http://web-kreation.com/tutorials/nice-login-and-signup-panel-using-mootools-12/)
- [Up and Down slider using JQuery](http://www.thatagency.com/design-studio-blog/2009/02/up-and-down-slider-using-jquery/)
- [Sliding top panel using mootools](http://woork.blogspot.in/2008/03/sliding-top-panel-using-mootools_05.html)